# Get Object Method Name From Within That Same Method

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects

Let's say I have an obj:

```
var app = {}
```

and a method inside the object

```
app = {
   init: function () {
   }
}
```

how would I go about obtaining the method name `'init'` inside of `init()` without specifically looking for `'init'`. This would be in the case that the method name could be anything and I can't rely on searching for a specific name.

```
app = {
   init: function () {
      //get 'init' method name here
   }
}
app.init();
```

I tried using `callee` but that brings back an *empty string*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a named function expression:

```
app = {
  init: function init() {
    console.log(arguments.callee.name);
  }
};

app.init();  // => "init"
```

Note that use of `arguments.callee` is forbidden in strict mode.

What you are doing in your example is assigning an anonymous function expression to the property named `init` on your object. The function itself does not have a name unless you use a named function expression.

Comment: Thanks, something so simple, didn't even think about declaring its name. That worked perfectly

Comment: I had used arguments.callee.name before, but for the life of me could not figure out why it was coming back as an empty string. Not declaring it was staring me right in the face. Ugh, need to step away for a little bit. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: just to be clear, that's actually a named function expression, not a function declaration.